# 'Cannot get' + path when refreshing through liveserver

Tags: javascript, lit-html, npm-live-server

I am a JS student and have a project-like problem using page and lit-html. My task is to make a SPA through 'live server' and a server, which is initiated on my pc. I have to install page and lit-html through npm. My issue is that when i start the page everything works except when the page refreshes i get 'Cannt GET' + the route on the screen and nothing else and the message 'Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at http://127.0.0.1:5500/favicon.ico (“default-src”).' in the console when i inspect.

I tried checking all my imports and the pathways, also tried to reinstall page and lit-html but can't seem to find the problem. Maybe it's something silly, but this is the second task with the same problem and i am getting frustrated.

Comment: Would be nice for you to share what your "live server" code looks like, so we can see what needs to be inspected.

Comment: Yeah, i it was the setting for the file in live server, it was set wrong.

Comment: Awesome. If you no longer need an answer could you answer the question yourself (and mark as answered) or close the question? Thank you!